# $push equivalent for map in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We can use `$push` (to add an element into an array) in update to `atomically` `update` a single document containing the array

However, I could not find a way to atomically `add a new key` to a map in a document.

I could

```
* read the document,
* read the map in it, 
* update the map in my code and 
* update the document in my code.
```

> But that is not atomic.

I am only dealing with a `single document` but that document has a map.

Is there a way I can update `(add a new key)` map atomically?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) with the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator is how you address individual elements.

Take the following document:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "map": {
        "field2": 1
    }

}
```

In order to add "field3" to the map you update like this:

```
db.collection.update({ "_id": 1 }, { "$set": { "map.field3": 2 } })
```

So now your document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "map": {
        "field2": 1,
        "field3": 2
    }
}
```