# Mongo Template's findAndModify is returning null values for adding or updating nested elements

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

My data is formatted as:

```
{
    "_id" : "149",
    "books" : {
       "32" : "0.12",
       "33" : "0.21"
    }
}
```

I would like to update/insert values inside the nested `books` document. If I insert a new row say `"39" : "0.19"`, then the updated document should look as below:

```
{
    "_id" : "149",
    "books" : {
       "32" : "0.12",
       "33" : "0.21",
       "39" : "0.19"
    }
}
```

And updates should work, the way they are meant to work. By updating the values.

I tried several ways, but couldn't update the way I wanted.

### Method1: Working but wrong result

```
MongoCollection<Document> document =  mongoTemplate.getCollection("booksCollection");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", storeId);

BasicDBObject bookDiscount = new BasicDBObject();
bookDiscount.put(bookId, discount);

BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
update.put('$push', new BasicDBObject("books", bookDiscount));

document.findOneAndUpdate(query, update);
```

### Method1 Output: Each value is added in a new row

```
{
    "_id" : "1664",
    "books" : [ 
        {
            "28" : NumberDecimal("0.75")
        }, 
        {
            "29" : NumberDecimal("0.18")
        }, 
        {
            "30" : NumberDecimal("0.23")
        }, 
        {
            "245" : NumberDecimal("0.26")
        }, 
        {
            "277" : NumberDecimal("0.13")
        }, 
        {
            "270" : NumberDecimal("0.19")
        }
    ]
}
```

### Method2: Working but wrong result

```
MongoCollection<Document> document =  mongoTemplate.getCollection("booksCollection");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", storeId);

BasicDBObject bookDiscount = new BasicDBObject();
bookDiscount.put(bookId, discount);

BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
update.put('$set', new BasicDBObject("books", bookDiscount));

document.findOneAndUpdate(query, update);
```

### Method2 Output: Value always gets replaced

```
{
    "_id" : "16644158",
    "locationInfRate" : {
        "2857" : NumberDecimal("0.68")
    },
    "_class" : "com.test.books"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I learned:

`$push` method pushes the data as a member of a list.
`$set` method updates the data, but for maps, it replaces data if the map is not correctly formatted in the query.

I edited my `$set` query to below format and it worked:

```
MongoCollection<Document> document =  mongoTemplate.getCollection("booksCollection");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", storeId);

BasicDBObject bookDiscount = new BasicDBObject();
bookDiscount.put("books." + bookId, discount);

update.put('$set', bookDiscount);

document.findOneAndUpdate(query, update);
```

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090548/push-equivalent-for-map-in-mongo